# Calibration of penalized (LASSO or ELasticNet) logistic regression models

Tags: logistic, classification, calibration, regularization

I would be very grateful for any help me with the following general query regarding calibration of penalized models with a binary outcome.

I would like my prediction model to be calibrated (mean prediction from model = observed event proportion); however, using penalized models (i.e., **glmnet** in R or **lassopack** in Stata) this appears not to be the case, whilst a cross-validated logistic model using the same variables is calibrated. Further, in the penalized models, the predicted probabilities seem to be compressed into a limited range with resulting predicted counts not closely approximating observed counts.

Am I correct in understanding that this results from the biased regression coefficients in the penalised model?

If one is attempting to develop a prediction model across levels of prediction risk (e.g., low, moderate & high), which needs the model to be adequately calibrated (rather than a one level classifier - say sensitivity at 90% specificity) is it acceptable to use penalized models (LASSO or elasticNet) for variable selection and then a cross validated logistic model containing only those variables?

Comment: Great question! For least-squares regression, it is known that using non-penalized OLS on variable subsets selected via LASSO works better than LASSO alone. I don't know about binary responses, though.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1001.0188.pdf
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1001.0188.pdf